# How to get activity object? (Android, Qt 5.2)

Tags: java-native-interface, android-activity, qt5

I need to get main activity, and I tried:

```
QAndroidJniEnvironment jniEnv;
jclass clsAct = jniEnv->FindClass("android/app/Activity");
qDebug() << "Activity: " << clsAct;

if( QAndroidJniObject::isClassAvailable("org/qtproject/qt5/android/bindings/QtActivity") )
{
    jclass clsApp = jniEnv->FindClass("org/qtproject/qt5/android/bindings/QtActivity");
    qDebug() << "QtActivity: " << clsApp;

    if( clsApp && clsAct )
    {
       jobject objAct = NULL;
       jmethodID mid = jniEnv->GetStaticMethodID( clsApp, "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;" );
       qDebug() << "activityMID: " << mid;

       if( mid )
       {
           objAct = jniEnv->CallStaticObjectMethod( clsApp, mid );
           qDebug() << "activityObj: " << objAct;
       }
   }
}
```

But on `jniEnv->FindClass(“org/qtproject/qt5/android/bindings/QtActivity”)` shoots error:

> D/Qt      ( 4074): mainwindow.cpp:32
>   (MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)): >>>>>> QtActivity:  0x0
>   W/dalvikvm( 4074): JNI WARNING: JNI function CallStaticVoidMethodV
>   called with exception pending W/dalvikvm( 4074):              in
>   Ldalvik/system/NativeStart;.run:()V (CallStaticVoidMethodV)
>   W/dalvikvm( 4074): Pending exception is: I/dalvikvm( 4074):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/qtproject/qt5/android/bindings/QtActivity I/dalvikvm( 4074):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method) I/dalvikvm( 4074): Caused
>   by: I/dalvikvm( 4074): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find
>   class "org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity" on path:
>   DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib]]

Comment: did you able to manage to make it work..i also stuck badly in similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284141/call-android-method-in-c-using-jni-and-pass-activity-context?noredirect=1#comment33884058_22284141